# The best way to call optional method in PHP?

Tags: php, methods

Which way will be better,

A. Checking existence of method to invoke:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        . . .
        if (is_callable([$obj, 'myMethod'])) {
            $obj->myMethod();
        }
        . . .
    }
}
```

or

B. have a blank method in the parent class

```
class Bar {
    protected function myMethod() {}
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    public function __construct() {
        . . .
        $obj->myMethod();
        . . .
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "optional method" in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should never need to be guessing whether an object has a method or not. You need to know whether that object has the method based on its type. You *should* not be checking what its type is either, typically, you should have a sane class hierarchy and require the correct types in the appropriate places:

```
function foo(MyType $bar) {
    ...
}
```

This function requires an object of class `MyType`, and you know what `MyType` can and cannot do. So no need to check for anything.

However, in some circumstances you may have to check manually, in which case there's `instanceof`:

```
if ($foo instanceof MyType) {
    ...
}
```

If that particular method does not fit well within a specific class hierarchy, then make an interface for it:

```
interface MyMethodInterface {
    public function myMethod();
}

class Foo implements MyMethodInterface {

    public function myMethod() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Then do the above type checks against `MyMethodInterface`.